# banner and interstitial ads units is not working

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

i am trying to display my admob ads on application but my ads unit is not working
Admob testing ads unit are working good.

[image]
[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8gCc.png)

[image]

[this is my ad units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BWkF.png)

[image]

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to show your code instead of post it in image

Comment: Post code here instead of image, it will help you to get answer quickly

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that your banner ad id is in your xml file when you are creating the banner ad.

This should be in your OnCreate and obviously I can't see your OnCreate in your code but I am just covering all the bases.

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "Ad ID");
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Furthermore, if you are test running your app on an emulator, you should have a "`.addTestDevice()`" when you build it. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes every thing is ok and admob testing ad id is also working but my ads unit id is not working

Comment: If it is newly created ad id, it will take some time to show up real ads. and if it is old ad id probably admob is not returning any inventory for your ad id for some reasons. to find out exact reason you can check error code in logcat which indicates the cause.